# What does this notation mean: $(\chi(D),p^j)$

Tags: combinatorics, notation, combinations, abelian-groups, characters

what does this notation mean:

$(\chi(D),p^j)$

where $\chi(D)$ - character of the group ring. D - element of the group of ring, p - prime number.

It is looks like a greatest common divisor, but it is not.

I found this notation in the book ***Addition theorems, H. B. MANN,  1965.***
[https://www.amazon.com/Addition-Theorems-H-B-Mann/dp/047056735X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047056735X)
without explanation:
[image]

Comment: Why do you think it is not the GCD? That would work in the proof, no?

Comment: Yes it is GCD!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, but the comment of David A. Craven help me to understand that it is in fact the **greatest common divisor** but in algebraic number field.

In fact, if we accept that this is a GCD, then the proof of the theorem will be true, as can be seen in the attached screenshot.

The prime number decomposition in algebraic number field confused me a little, so I did not immediately understand this notation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).